# Spring Integration - Dynamic MailReceiver configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm pretty new to `spring-integration` anyway I'm using it in order to receive mails and elaborate them.

I used this spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:configuration.properties" }, encoding = "UTF-8", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
public class MailReceiverConfiguration {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MailReceiverConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmailTransformerService emailTransformerService;

    // Configurazione AE
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inboundChannelAE() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name= {"aeProps"})
    public Properties aeProps() {
        Properties javaMailPropertiesAE = new Properties();
        javaMailPropertiesAE.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
        javaMailPropertiesAE.put("mail.debug", Boolean.TRUE);
        javaMailPropertiesAE.put("mail.auth.debug", Boolean.TRUE);
        javaMailPropertiesAE.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        javaMailPropertiesAE.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        return javaMailPropertiesAE;
    }
    @Bean(name="mailReceiverAE")
    public MailReceiver mailReceiverAE(@Autowired MailConfigurationBean mcb, @Autowired @Qualifier("aeProps") Properties javaMailPropertiesAE) throws Exception {

        return ConfigurationUtil.getMailReceiver("imap://USERNAME:PASSWORD@MAILSERVER:PORT/INBOX", new BigDecimal(2), javaMailPropertiesAE);
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter( autoStartup = "true", 
                            channel = "inboundChannelAE", 
                            poller = {@Poller(fixedRate = "${fixed.rate.ae}", 
                            maxMessagesPerPoll = "${max.messages.per.poll.ae}") })
    public MailReceivingMessageSource pollForEmailAE(@Autowired MailReceiver mailReceiverAE) {
        MailReceivingMessageSource mrms = new MailReceivingMessageSource(mailReceiverAE);
        return mrms;
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "inboundChannelAE", outputChannel = "transformerChannelAE")
    public MessageBean transformitAE( MimeMessage mailMessage ) throws Exception {
        // amministratore email inbox
        MessageBean messageBean = emailTransformerService.transformit(mailMessage);
        return messageBean;
    }

    @Splitter(inputChannel = "transformerChannelAE", outputChannel = "nullChannel")
    public List<Message<?>> splitIntoMessagesAE(final MessageBean mb) {

        final List<Message<?>> messages = new ArrayList<Message<?>>();

        for (EmailFragment emailFragment : mb.getEmailFragments()) {
            Message<?> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(emailFragment.getData())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.FILENAME, emailFragment.getFilename())
                    .setHeader("directory", emailFragment.getDirectory()).build();
            messages.add(message);
        }

        return messages;
    }
}
```

So far so good.... I start my micro-service and there is this component listening on the specified mail server and mails are downloaded.

Now I have this requirement: mail server configuration (I mean the string `"imap://USERNAME:PASSWORD@MAILSERVER:PORT/INBOX"`) must be taken from a database and it can be configurable. In any time a system administrator can change it and the mail receiver must use the new configuration.

As far as I understood I should create a new instance of MailReceiver when a new configuration is present and use it in the `InboundChannelAdapter`

Is there any best practice in order to do it? I found this solution: [ImapMailReceiver NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure) [THROTTLED];](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824241/imapmailreceiver-no-store-attempt-on-read-only-folder-failure-throttled)

In this solution I can inject the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler if I define it in my Configuration class; I can also inject the DirectChannel but every-time I should create a new MailReceiver and a new ImapIdleChannelAdapter without considering this WARN message I get when the

```
ImapIdleChannelAdapter starts:
java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanfactory at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:79) at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.onInit(AbstractMailReceiver.java:403)
```

Is there a better way to satisfy my scenario?

Thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the Java DSL and dynamic flow registration.

[Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#java-dsl-runtime-flows).

That way, you can unregister the old flow and register a new one, each time the configuration changes.

It will automatically handle injecting dependencies such as the bean factory.