# How to enable IMAPFolder read-write mode in Spring Mail Integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using the following Java code in my Spring Boot App (v2.1.6.RELEASE):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {

    SearchTermStrategy searchTermStrategy = (supportedFlags, folder) -> {
        SearchTerm search = new AndTerm(new SubjectTerm("trigger the build"), new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
        return search;
    };

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imaps://usr:pwd@imap.host.com/INBOX").searchTermStrategy(searchTermStrategy).shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true).get(),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> logMail(payload))
            .get();
}
```

But this throws an exception `com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A7 NO Command received in Invalid state.` when there is a matching message. This seems to be an issue with the IMAP folder being set as Read-only by default.

There is an `onInit` protected method in the `AbstractMailReceiver` class which opens the Folder in Read-Write mode. And I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23825940/1594823) to call the `ImapMailReceiver.afterPropertiesSet()` which eventually calls the `onInit` method but that gives me `An external 'receiver' ... can't be modified.`:

```
@Bean
private ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
    ImapMailReceiver receiver = new ImapMailReceiver("...URL...");
    receiver.afterPropertiesSet();
    //receiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
    return receiver;
}
```

Can someone please guide me on how to set the folder in read-write mode?

**P.S.** In plain Java code I could set the same using `inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)` and this works.

### EDIT 1

If I use the code like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {

    SearchTermStrategy searchTermStrategy = (supportedFlags, folder) -> {
        SearchTerm search = new AndTerm(new SubjectTerm("trigger the build"),
                new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
        return search;
    };

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(receiver()))
            .log()
            .get();
}

@Bean
public ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
    return new ImapMailReceiver(IMAP_URL);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'mailListener.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.initializeAdapter(SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.java:186) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

### EDIT 2

If I use the code as below:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {

    SearchTermStrategy searchTermStrategy = (supportedFlags, folder) -> {
        SearchTerm search = new AndTerm(new SubjectTerm("trigger the build"),
                new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
        return search;
    };

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(receiver()).searchTermStrategy(searchTermStrategy).shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true).get(),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> logMail(payload))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
    return new ImapMailReceiver(IMAP_URL);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An external 'receiver' [imaps://.../INBOX] can't be modified.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.dsl.MailInboundChannelAdapterSpec.assertReceiver(MailInboundChannelAdapterSpec.java:85) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.dsl.ImapMailInboundChannelAdapterSpec.searchTermStrategy(ImapMailInboundChannelAdapterSpec.java:51) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.emailapp.InboundEmailConfig.mailListener(InboundEmailConfig.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xxx.emailapp.InboundEmailConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ab01b59.CGLIB$mailListener$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xxx.emailapp.InboundEmailConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ab01b59$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8ee22ea2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.emailapp.InboundEmailConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ab01b59.mailListener(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring an explicit receiver bean works

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {

    SearchTermStrategy searchTermStrategy = (supportedFlags, folder) -> {
        SearchTerm search = new AndTerm(new SubjectTerm("trigger the build"),
                new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
        return search;
    };

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(receiver()))
            .log()
            .get();
}

@Bean
public ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
    return new ImapMailReceiver("imaps://usr:pwd@imap.host.com/INBOX");
}
```

**EDIT**

You must not call `get()` on the receiver spec; the framework needs a reference to the spec itself to properly initialize the bean(s).

Comment: You must not call `get()` on the receiver spec; the framework needs a reference to the spec itself to properly initialize the bean(s).

Comment: Or you should declare that `Mail.imapInboundAdapter()` definition together with the `get()` as a standalone `@Bean`

Comment: Thank you! But still I am getting `An external 'receiver' [imaps://usr:pwd@host/INBOX] can't be modified.`

Comment: That message implies you no longer using the code in the first block, and you are using the DSL to modify the receiver after it has been created. Edit your question to show the full stack trace.

Comment: If I use your code as is then I get the `no pollers available`, edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: You still need to add a poller, as you have in your first code block, unless there's a default poller in the context.

Comment: Sorry but still no joy (please see Edit 2), what am I missing :'(

Comment: You are now using an externally declared `receiver()`; you have to set the search strategy on it, rather than on the adapter via the DSL.

Comment: @GaryRussell may i know how to fetch new messages from above code?

Comment: @Saikat can you please add complete working code for mail listener as well as how  to fetch new mails ?

Comment: @VGH do you want to read emails using Spring or any working Java code would suffice?

Comment: @Saikat We're using Springboot for our project. So Spring code will be helpfull. We're able to read emails by fetching the messages. We want to add a message listener so that we can perform some tasks when a new message arrives.